# Background image not showing CSS

Tags: css, image, background-image

I would like to have a background-image on my website. For some reason when I use a placeholder (`background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1920x500) no-repeat center top;)`, the placeholder appears with no issues, but when I use the image sitting on my laptop... It does not show.  Below is how I display the image:

```
background: url("/images/about.jpeg") no-repeat center top;
```

I also tried:

```
background-image: url("/images/about.jpeg") no-repeat center top;
```

and I get the same result.  Please assist the new guy to CSS

Below is the file structure:

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking your file path might be off but thats just a guess, what's your file structure look like?

Comment: The information you provided will not be enough to help you!

Comment: Most of the time this is a path issue. Provide the paths to all of your files please, including where this is included. Also, are there any errors in your dev tools? Please also read all of the links in my next comment.

Comment: [Please, do more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) then **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).

Comment: Added the file structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your stylesheet is inside the `CSS` folder, the CSS rule should be like this:

```
background: url("../images/about.jpeg") no-repeat center top;
```

i.e., go *out*  of the "css" folder and *into*  the "images" folder

Answer (score 0):

css file is unable to locate your image.

you have to change your image url to

```
url("../image_url")
```